# WCF and Nested Classes

Tags: c#, wcf, class, nested

First, I want to say that I have a fully functional WCF service that uses many endpoints and service contracts with no problems whatsoever.

Ok so here is my scenario. I have a class that is nested in another class.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Database { 
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MyTable { 


    }
}
```

On my endpoint I am referencing an interface that takes into account the use of those classes. My interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDatabase { 
    [OperationContract]
    void GetData(Database.MyTable MyTableData);
}
```

My endpoint looks like this:

```
<endpoint address="Database" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
name="Database" contract="MyNamespace.IDatabase" ></endpoint>
```

Now, on the client I run into an error stating that metadata can't find a reference. I know exactly where the issue lies, and its the fact that this class is nested inside of another class. To fix this issue or really workaround it, I have been doing the following to my interface.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://MyNamesapce"]
public interface IDatabase { 
    [OperationContract]
    void GetData(Database.MyTable MyTableData);
}
```

That resolves all issues and the client can generate metadata perfectly. I know I am missing out an understanding a very important piece of WCF here. I am more or less looking for answers to why specifying a Namespace on that service contract that references a nested class helps resolve my metadata generation issue, the answer should be obvious but I am blinded at the moment.

**EDIT 1**

Also, if I could get away with fixing this issue in the app.config I would love to.

Comment: This [DataContract] on "public class MyTable" should be [DataMember]

Comment: Attribute 'DataMember' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations.